# No Able To Get Returned JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I am able to returned value in alert form from remote php script.  However when I console.log(IPAddress) my value is undefined.  My Goal is to establish value of IPAddress from json response.  Always a single value in json response. Example: {"ip":"192.168.1.1"}

Here is my code:

```
var IPAddress = function(){
    $.getJSON("http://domain.com/assets/php/get-ip.php/?    callback=DisplayIP",function(data){
                            //alert(result['ip']);

//alert(data.ip);
return(data.ip);
});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to Parse Json in order to read it. You can do this by using `JSON.parse()` method.

So, simply use `JSON.Parse(data.ip);` to get your data

Comment: `$.getJSON` parses the response.

Comment: return JSON.parse(data.ip) gives me same undefined result

Comment: @user3431682 First log this JSON.stringify(data).. and tell what it returns..

Comment: {"ip":"192.168.1.1"} - stringify

Comment: @user3431682 Check the linked question. Your problem is something completely different from what these guys tell you.

Comment: does this apply to getajax or getjson?

Comment: @user3431682 `getJSON` uses `$.ajax` behind the sense, so this applies to all of them. After all this is the asynchronous nature of Ajax itself.